# codeigniter query issue with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to write a query to fetch one product data from table. but that product name has a space in between  words that is not getting from table using where condition.

```
public function get_data_print1($item, $start_date, $end_date) {      
  $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('duplex');
          $this->db->where("item_name",$item);
  $this->db->group_by(array("item_name"));

         $this->db->where('duplex.item_dated >=', $start_date);
        $this->db->where('duplex.item_dated <=', $end_date);
        $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query->result();
 }
```

product name in my table is:  *duplex180 17x30*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was not a query issue. Actually when I post item name full name not get posted because i didnt put that with double quotes.

```
<select class="form-control" name="item"  id="item" >
  <option value="">----Select------</option>
  <?php 
  foreach($items as $ven) {
      echo '<option value="'.$ven->item_name.'">'.$ven->item_name.'</option>';
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('duplex');
$this->db->where("item_name",$item);
$this->db->where('duplex.item_dated BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date');
$this->db->group_by(array("item_name"));
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: this is only the issue of space in item name. when we use like operator,it fetch all data with any word in this product name,i want exact this product details only